# Android 12 and 14 GPUWatch missing

Tags: cpu, android, testing, development

I am doing some generic testing for performance for Android 12-14 with our work build / devices. On two of the devices (XCover5 and Active Tab5 Pro running Android 13 and 14 respectively) i have enabled developer options, and under the heading 'Games' there is a tool you can enable called GPUWatch which allows you to see CPU, GPU and FPS information.

General info on GPU Watch : https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-gamedev/gpuwatch-userguide/gpuwatch_v2.html

On an XCover7 with Android 14, i have enabled developer options and when i scroll down, i see the heading 'Games' but the GPU Watch is missing.

Similarly on an A32 running Android 12 GPU Watch is missing from the device. These are factory resets, and i can find no common factor for why this useful tool is missing.

Anyone experienced this and how did you fix it?